# create directory with incremental version

Tags: xml, ant

I have a situation where i need to copy file from one location to another after creating a directory.

source F:/direcoty one (this is where script will sit)

target H:/folder1/folder2/naming_convention_SN1_date

catch is "SN" part need to increment by one each time

i am trying below code. but not sure how to make it incremental

```
<b> 
<target name="create directory">
    <mkdir dir="H:/folder1/folder2/{${JOB_NAME}.${BUILD_NUMBER}.date}"/>
</target>
    <copy todir="H:/folder1/folder2/{${JOB_NAME}.${BUILD_NUMBER}.date}">
 <fileset dir="src_dir" include="**/*"/>
</copy>
```

> /b>

Appreciate your help !!
Rose

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you need an incrementing build number there is a buildnumber task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html

Comment: Thanks !! Below is naming convention of folder

Comment: Thanks !! Below is naming convention of folder application_buildtype_Buldnumber_date. now script need to create this folder every time and in build number need to increment. lets say google_test_abd9_01282014 is already exist and script need to create next folder and which need to be google_test_abd10_currentdate. and copy file and folders to this newly created folder from source path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping!! I figured this out. putting it in this post if in case somebody need it.

```
`@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set max_number=0
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)

for /d %%d in (destination_location\folder_name_ABC%max_number%_%mydate%%) do (
set current_directory=%%~nxd
    call:StrLength name_length !current_directory!
 echo name_length
 echo !current_directory!
 echo !name_length!

    call:Substring directory_number,!current_directory!,26,!name_length!
    if !directory_number! gtr !max_number! (
        set max_number=!directory_number!
    )
)
set /a max_number+=1

mkdir "destination_location\folder_name_ABC%max_number%_%mydate%%"

echo Directory create = folder_name_ABC%max_number%_%mydate%%

echo copy in process..........

xcopy "Source_location"    "Destination_location\%folder_name%_BLD%max_number%_%mydate%%"     /D /E /Y

echo copy completed:

GOTO :EOF

:Substring
::Substring(retVal,string,startIndex,length)
:: extracts the substring from string starting at startIndex for the specified length
 SET string=%2%
 SET startIndex=%3%
 SET length=%4%
 if "%4" == "0" goto :noLength
 CALL SET _substring=%%string:~%startIndex%,%length%%%
 goto :substringResult
 :noLength
 CALL SET _substring=%%string:~%startIndex%%%
 :substringResult
 set "%~1=%_substring%"
GOTO :EOF
:StrLength
::StrLength(retVal,string)
::returns the length of the string specified in %2 and stores it in %1
set #=%2%
set length=0
:stringLengthLoop
if defined # (set #=%#:~1%&set /A length += 1&goto stringLengthLoop)
::echo the string is %length% characters long!
set "%~1=%length%"
GOTO :EOF`
```

Thanks!!